# Trelby not installing in 16.04

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

Trying to install trelby by using `sudo dpkg -i trelby_2.2_all.deb` produces this error:

```
Selecting previously unselected package trelby.
(Reading database ... 267174 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack trelby_2.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking trelby (2.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of trelby:
 trelby depends on python-wxgtk2.8; however:
  Package python-wxgtk2.8 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package trelby (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 trelby
```

It clearly looks like a dependency issue, but I don't know how to resolve this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written [in this Debian mailing list](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2016/01/msg01163.html):

> It's a problem with Trelby:
>   https://github.com/oskusalerma/trelby/commit/50c46f2249ca5b094c5e712a872e1dadbd8dfdfa
>
> Looks like it was fixed, but no new package was built.
>
> You might want to report a bug to the Trelby developer, and preferably
>   ask them to list the requirements for the package too. "Ubuntu/Debian"
>   doesn't tell you much.

You might also consider compiling it from source.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Andrea. I sent a message on their group form - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/trelby - asking if they could build new .deb packages for Ubuntu 16.04 and post on their website.

I'm not a developer or a coder, otherwise I would try to package it myself.

Comment: If this solved your question, consider upvoting it and accepting it.

Comment: I ended up having to - rather painstakingly for an end-user with novice developer experience - compile the program from source and package it into an installable .deb file, but once I did it worked like a charm. I guess we'll have to wait for the dev's to package version 2.3, which works with 16.04 and up.

Comment: @Jesse great. You might consider writing an answer with the process you followed to compile it. :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same dependency problem with the .deb package on Ubuntu 17.04, but installing Trelby from source was fairly simple.

1. Install `python-lxml` and `python-wxgtk3.0` from the repository:

   ```
   sudo apt install python-lxml python-wxgtk3.0
   ```
2. Download and extract the Zip file or clone the [Git repository](https://github.com/oskusalerma/trelby). Example:

   ```
   sudo apt install git
   git clone https://github.com/oskusalerma/trelby.git
   cd trelby
   ```
3. Navigate to the trelby folder and enter:

   ```
   sudo python setup.py install
   ```

   Done, you can now type, or add a shortcut pointing to, `/opt/trelby/bin/trelby` to start Trelby

Comment: Thank you so much David for clarifying wilks answer. It opens now, and I hope it will work.

Comment: Yeah, thanks David, I didn't even know I could use `apt` instead of `apt-get`

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get 2.2 working when I was trying to install wxgtk3.0 , I received the following dialog:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 trelby : Depends: python-wxgtk2.8 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried `apt-get -f install` as suggested and the 2.8 packages installed. I then reinstalled the 2.2 deb and everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get Trelby working today on Ubuntu 16.04 64bit by:

1. Downloading the tar.gz file from http://www.trelby.org/download
2. Unpacking the `/trelby` dir from the tar.gz file to `/opt` (using sudo)
3. Manually editing the files and applying the changes described here (using sudo): https://github.com/oskusalerma/trelby/commit/50c46f2249ca5b094c5e712a872e1dadbd8dfdfa

   - (Surely there must be a smarter way to do this, but I don't know how)
4. Moving (again using sudo) the `/opt/trelby/trelby.desktop` file to `/usr/share/applications`
5. Installing `python-wxgtk3.0` and `python-crypto` using apt (they're both in the repositories)

After this, Trelby can be launched from the Dash.

If anyone can optimize these steps, that would be awesome :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try this: `sudo dpkg -i trelby_2.2_all.deb --force-depends`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Sujeet. However, install still didn't work. Running that command in Terminal produces this error:

dpkg: error processing package trelby (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 --force-depends
 trelby